# How to create a new branch from old commit using magit

Tags: magit

When viewing the commit log, can I select a commit and checkout that commit as the head of a new branch?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a magit-log buffer, place your cursor over the commit you want to branch from and run <kbd>M-x</kbd>`magit-branch-and-checkout`<kbd>enter</kbd>. You'll be prompted for a branch name, then for a starting point, the default starting point will be the branch under your cursor so you can just hit <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Comment: `b B` should run that command as well.